# Inject iframe javascript code to parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need iframe js code to be part of the parent window. there is a way?

Answer (score 0):

**Calling from parent to iframe:**

Suppose that your frame is called "myTargetFrame" and the function you're going to call is myFunction():

```
document.getElementById('myTargetFrame').contentWindow.myFunction();
```

You can use also `window.frames` instead of `document.getElementById`

**Calling from iframe to parent:**

```
parent.document.formname.fieldname.value = [value you want to set]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var wnd = window;
  if(wnd.parent){
    wnd = wnd.parent;
  }
  wnd.$.globalEval('$.unblockUI();Dialog.hide();');
</script>
```

This ofcourse uses jquery, but all it does is calls execScript or eval on the current window.
I don't think there is a better way do this.